# Get OS information with WMI from Small Business Server 2011 for Windows 2008 virtual machine

Tags: windows-server-2008, virtualbox, windows, wmi

In my organization, the main server is  Windows Small Business 2011. It uses a WMI service (I think) to get the Security and Update status of computers on the network.

I have a Server 2008 virtual machine in VirtualBox with bridged network adapter. The SBS will not correctly get the status of, nor the operating system of, the Server 2008 VM. What settings do I have wrong / can I actually do this for a virtual machine in the first place?

--

I do not know what further information might be needed, just ask and I will post.

Comment: if its a new w2k8 server then the firewall could be on.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the SBS console is getting that information from AD, Exchange, WSUS, etc.

> The console will only display status information for domain-joined
>   computers from the following three OUs:
>
> ```
> OU=Domain Controllers,DC=Domain,DC=local
> OU=SBSComputers,OU=Computers,OU=MyBusiness,DC=Domain,DC=local
> OU=SBSServers,OU=Computers,OU=MyBusiness,DC=Domain,DC=local
> ```

This link will help you troubleshoot network connectivity, if the issue is that the VirtualBox server is showing up as offline.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/sbs/archive/2009/01/30/why-is-my-computer-status-not-showing-online-in-the-sbs-console.aspx

If the issue is that the VirtualBox server isn't showing up at all, you'll need to make sure it's in the SBSServers OU.